# Infinitesimal time in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, syntax

I have a question

I want to compare two time object and wanna always pass the compare in the first time :

```
 def compare_time(time)
   @memory_time ||= Time.new(1999,01,01)
   if time > @memory_time
     puts "pass the compare"
   end
   @memory_time = Time.now
 end
```

I use the Time.new(1999,01,01) be the infinitesimal time, but I think the syntax(tips) is ugly and isn't always work.

So I wanna know is there any CONSTANT or other better method can be a infinitesimal time in ruby?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *infinitesimal* time. I know the expression from differential calculus, where it (colloquially speaking) means "infinitely close to zero", but this would make sense only with time intervals, but not with points in time, which you seem to be using.

Comment: The  infinitesimal time that I hope it smaller than any time object, so I can let any time pass "time > @memory_time" when I first call the function

Comment: It also makes no much sense to me. Most computers can't set older time then Unix Epoch start, so [Time.at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-at) may come handy in this case. `Time.at(0) == 1970-01-01 00:00:00` .

Comment: @joanbm, you're right, it satisfy my function-needed, do you want to reply in answer dialog?

Comment: @joanbm, oh no, I found I can set Time.new(1000,01,01). So Time.at(0) is a good solution but not perfect.

Comment: @joanbm: In Ruby, you can also use `Time.at` with negative numbers, to refer to dates before the epoch. Tsao seems to look for a way to express a time point representing *negative infinity*, so if Ruby would have something to denote the smallest integral number, this would do the trick - but Ruby doesn't. I suggest that Tsao manually calulates the number of seconds since the Big Bang and defines a constant with the negative value of this number. At least if the [Hartle-Hawking](http://www.hawking.org.uk/the-beginning-of-time.html) assumption is correct, this should be sufficient.

Comment: @user1934428 Without a more specific context, it is meaningless speculate what he really wants to achieve. It may be just an another example of [Xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: He gave a specification in his comment (not in his posting), when he said *smaller than any time object*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because ruby Time makes comparison with fractions of seconds. We may use to_f method to see the difference between t1 and t2:

```
def compare_time(time)
   @memory_time ||= Time.new(1999,01,01)
   if time.to_f > @memory_time.to_f
     puts "pass the compare"
   end
   @memory_time = Time.now
 end
```

I think this one help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Compare

  attr_accessor :memory_time

    def compare_time(time)
      unless @memory_time && (time < @memory_time)
        puts "pass the compare" 
      else
        puts "no pass the compare"
      end
      @memory_time = Time.now
    end

  end

compare = Compare.new
compare.compare_time(Time.new(1000,01,01)) #=> pass the compare
compare.compare_time(Time.new(1000,01,01)) #=> no pass the compare
compare.compare_time(Time.new(2018,01,01)) #=> pass the compare
```

I find the solution, the code always puts "pass the compare" first time, when execute once, @memory_time exist time object and compare with the input time object.